# Failed to start namenode.java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: hadoop

iam using hadoop apache  2.7.1 high availability cluster that consists of 
two name nodes mn1,mn2 and 3 journal nodes

but while i was working on cluster i faced the following error

when i issue start-dfs.sh mn1 is standby and mn2 is active

but after that if one of theses two namenodes are off there is no possibility
to turn it on again
 and here are the last lines of log of one of these two name nodes

```
2017-08-05 09:37:21,063 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Need to save fs image? false (staleImage=true, haEnabled=true, isRollingUpgrade=false)
2017-08-05 09:37:21,063 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameCache: initialized with 3 entries 72 lookups
2017-08-05 09:37:21,088 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Finished loading FSImage in 7052 msecs
2017-08-05 09:37:21,300 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: RPC server is binding to mn2:8020
2017-08-05 09:37:21,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2017-08-05 09:37:21,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8020
2017-08-05 09:37:21,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemState MBean
2017-08-05 09:37:21,354 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: Path /opt/hadoop/metadata_dir should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
2017-08-05 09:37:21,361 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseManager.getNumUnderConstructionBlocks(LeaseManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getCompleteBlocksTotal(FSNamesystem.java:5741)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startCommonServices(FSNamesystem.java:1063)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.startCommonServices(NameNode.java:678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:664)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:811)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
2017-08-05 09:37:21,364 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2017-08-05 09:37:21,365 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at mn2/192.168.25.22
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be

```
1.Namenode PORT may be Change for each NODE.
```

Comment: as i commented when i issue start-dfs.sh both namenodes start normally but after that there is no possibility to start namenode again could that be becuase of port change abd how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

**This is a particularly vexing problem.**

1. Swallow IllegalStateExceptions thrown by removeShutdownHook in FileSystem. The javadoc states:

   public boolean removeShutdownHook(Thread hook)
   Throws:
   IllegalStateException - If the virtual machine is already in the process of shutting down

So if we are getting this exception, it MEANS we are already in the process of shutdown, so we CANNOT, try what we may, removeShutdownHook. If Runtime had a method Runtime.isShutdownInProgress(), we could have checked for it before the removeShutdownHook call. As it stands, there is no such method. In my opinion, this would be a good patch regardless of the needs for this JIRA.

2. Not send SIGTERMs from the NM to the MR-AM in the first place. Rather we should expose a mechanism for the NM to politely tell the AM its no longer needed and should shutdown asap. Even after this, if an admin were to kill the MRAppMaster with a SIGTERM, the JobHistory would be lost defeating the purpose of 3614

Comment: my virtual machine still works and other services on it which are journalnode,DFSZKFailoverController,QuorumPeerMain still works without exit so my virtual machine is not in the process of shutting down

Comment: and does what happens considered as bug in hadoop and how to fix it in this state ?

Answer (score 0):

i discovered that my problem was in journal node and not in namenode 
even though the log of namenode shows the error mentioned in question

jps shows journal node but it is fake because journal node service is shut down 
even though it is found in jps output

so as a solution i issue hadoop-daemon.sh stop journalnode
then hadoop-daemon.sh start journalnode

and then namenode starts to work again